# How to create AzureML environement and add required packages

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I want to use add some packages to the environment for AzureML environment. What is the way for that?

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple way for creating the environment for experiment.

```
from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies
```

**Create a Python environment for the experiment**

```
my_env = Environment("my-env")
```

**Ensure the required packages are installed**

```
packages = CondaDependencies.create(conda_packages=['pandas','numpy'],
                                    pip_packages=['mlflow','azureml-mlflow'])
my_env.python.conda_dependencies = packages
```

Then, we can use this env as follows:

**Create a script config**

```
script_config = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory=experiment_folder,
                                script='training_script.py',
                                environment=my_env)
```

**submit the experiment**

```
experiment = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='my_experiment)
run = experiment.submit(config=script_config)
RunDetails(run).show()
run.wait_for_completion()
```